# ExchangeNET - A Windows Stack Exchange client [WIP]

Tags: app, placeholder, windows

> **Author's Note**
>   This is very much a work in progress. If it weren't for the requirement that apps have a registered Stack Apps post to write, I wouldn't even have posted this yet.

## What is ExchangeNET?

ExchangeNET is (or will be) a Windows client for the Stack Exchange network. I'm taking inspiration from the Stack Exchange app, and a number of other clients, and combining it all into one big Windows package, bringing together as much of the Stack Exchange functionality as I can.

## How do I get it?

You don't. Yet. This is a work-in-progress app, and isn't even ready for a beta stage yet - I'll update this post as and when the app gets updates.